# Can I expect PostScript to end with "end end"?

Tags: pdf, postscript

I'm writing a PostScript parser. 
I'm getting my PostScript from a PDF. I'm not sure why but sometimes my PostScript ends with gibberish.

```
<0053>
<0072>
endbfchar
endcmap CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop end end
1
><0Ö
```

My question is. Can I assume that all valid PostScript will end with the word "end"

If thats the case then I can just cut off any extra characters I see at the end of the file.

Thanks!

Comment: You get this gibberish even if you only read as much data as the object contains? Is it present in the PDF as well?

Comment: Can you post an example of such a file ? You absolutely cannot assume that a valid PostScript program will end with any specific byte sequence. The other question is how are you getting PostScript from a PDF file ? And why do you need a PostScript interpreter ? You do realise that a parser simply isn't going to be good enough, you need an interpreter to handle full PostScript ?

Comment: Do you write a *PDF* parser, or a *PostScript* parser? What means "getting my PostScript from a PDF"?

Answer (score 2):

No: You cannot expect a valid PostScript stream ending with "end". Moreover there is no specific byte sequence denoting the end of PostScript stream. There may anything at the end of a PostScript program. For example you can encounter binary token encoded for `eexec`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky, the file will end after `%%EOF`, according to [Adobe's DSC convention (archived copy)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170818010030/http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/postscript/pdfs/5002.EPSF_Spec.pdf).
Maybe it ends with ASCII `EOT` (UNIX) or `SUB` (MS-DOS), maybe it ends with an arbitrary character.
"The file ends where the file ends"; that's the rule of PostScript.